# group by on two column(c1,c2) with order created_at desc in mysql

Tags: mysql

I tried to get data with group by on two column with  order By created_at(timestamp) descending. I am using

```
SELECT *,'count(*) as total',max(created_at) as created_at 
FROM `property_basic_info` GROUP BY project_id,posting_as 
ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

But did not get exact result

Comment: But what is "exact result"? and what type of incorrectness? Provide a sample (as textual CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO) with desired output and detailed explanations.

Comment: If your table contains more than 3 columns mentioned in the query then your query is incorrect. GROUP BY is incomplete, and all another columns in the output will receive indefinite values.

Comment: You are misusing MySQL's [notorious nonstandard extension to GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html). Disable that extension with `SET sql_mode = CONCAT_WS(',',@@sql_mode, 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY')`, then try your query again. You'll need more terms in your GROUP BY clause.

Comment: `count(*) as total` shouldn't be in quotes.

Comment: please write query.

Comment: I want data with order by date as name created_at descending with group by two column